# Is it possible to merge 2 signed messages in one transaction?

Tags: ethereum

Someone sent me signed message (transfer). I want to broadcast it to Ethereum network on my behalf, and cover up the fees.

I also have my signed message (transfer), and want to combine them both into 1 transaction.

Is it possible to merge them?

Or somehow optimise this using other method?

**The main goal is**: combined transaction need to be 1 and unique. So this combined amount of tokens will be processed by contract without the risk that a 3rd party will infiltrate the association.

Comment: I'm confused about the combination of "signed message" and "transfer" - can you specify what kind of message do you mean? Is it a text/binary message signed using an ECDSA algorithm, such as [this one](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth.html#sign) and you want to concat both original messages? Or do you mean the `data` field of a transaction (possibly transferring tokens or ETH) and your goal is to perform both transfers in one transaction? Please specify, ideally with steps to reproduce the current status.

Comment: @PetrHejda yes, the first one. Not just because need to save on transfer fees. But because this will be easier to contract identify this combined (concated) transaction then as one.

Comment: @PetrHejda the main goal is: combined transaction need to be 1 and unique. So this combined amount of tokens will be processed by contract without the risk that a 3rd party will infiltrate the association.

Comment: Are there token transfer transactions or something else? What's as the payload. This sounds like a xyquestion: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa yes, token transfer. The goal is real. For example OpenSea transaction 0x60b9cad2e51cc9a240f4c8254c4fd880bd733b537ae8b29f8dcfcb47d6cfc723 (Polygon). You can see that contract made 3 transfers from 2 different addresses. But does it possible to do the same without contract, by simply concatenating two raw transactions?

Comment: See the short answer no below.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. The way ECC encryption works is that you can't predict the outcome of encryption. So you can't just take encrypted result 1 + encrypted result 2 and get encrypted result 3.

Depending on the reason you are trying to do this, I could suggest a feasible solution. For example if you are trying to transact on someone's behalf to save them the gas, perhaps you can look at Meta Transactions.

Alternatively if you are trying to do something requiring multiple parties to sign something you can look at multisig.

I think for an abstract question like this you should probably provide a bit more context, so those answering have a chance to help.

Comment: But how OpenSea, using users offchain signed message (from offer purchase), combine it to 1 transaction with few outputs then? (0x60b9cad2e51cc9a240f4c8254c4fd880bd733b537ae8b29f8dcfcb47d6cfc723, Polygon)